# Xcode randomly modifies my schemes content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Whenever I switch branch or trigger a build, I'm getting my `xschemes` modified by **Xcode**, it seemed to happens since the last OS version. My schemes are shared amongst different target. Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

It goes from:

```
<BuildableProductRunnable
     runnableDebuggingMode = "0">
```

To:

```
<RemoteRunnable
         runnableDebuggingMode = "2"
         BundleIdentifier = "com.apple.Carousel"
         RemotePath = "/$(PRODUCT_NAME)">
```

Here is a screenshot of the whole change in git:
[image]

Comment: This happens to me in a specific project, when I change between different simulators.

Comment: Any updates on this one @Jaythaking

Comment: @Amit do you have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, @Jaythaking.  It started happening recently only

Comment: Couldn't find a fix unfortunately :/ Not a lot of ressources online for this issue @Amit

Comment: I have the similar issue but in my case its the opposite. Runnabledebuggingmode = "0" is being added and rest removed